# Magento tutorial to work with product collections and databases

Tags: magento, collections, product

looking for tutorial to work with product collections like,

```
Upsell products (just an example),
Grouping upsell products by categories,
accessing databases and get items by magento's MVC.
```

Sharing relevant tutorials is much appreciated.

Comment: asking for off-site resources like tutorials are off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tutorials available.

Start with these:

[Product Types in magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype)

[Related products, Up-sells, Cross-sells in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/related-products-up-sells-cross-sells-in-magento/)

[Product Collections in Magento](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-product-collection)